# How do I plot a vector (with a magnetic heading and magnitude) in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vector, heading

I have a table with a year's worth of wind data for a specific latitude longitude. I want to plot this as an arrow in Google Maps. Each data point has a timestamp, heading (true), and magnitude (knots), but it is just contained in a spreadsheet.

I was thinking the easiest way is to just create a new layer using geoJSON data, but I've never used geoJSON before.

How can I plot this in Google Map api v3? Thanks!

EDIT:

I did some research, and I think the best way is to just place a marker over the lat long point, and generate a ton of arrow images (probably in 5 degree and .5 knot increments, so I don't have a million images). Then just title each arrow based on its parameters (something like 01030.png, where 010 is the direction and 30 stands for 3.0 knots) and when the script calls for the marker image, just include those attributes when it calls for the image name.

I'll post the code when I make it, so other people can see.

Comment: Q1: What do you want to display? Q2: What have you tried? Q3: Where is your code?

Comment: Perhaps a [symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols) might work.

Comment: How about [polylines with arrow symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-arrow?hl=nl) in tandem with a [timeline using crossfilter.js](http://brendankenny.github.io/crossfilter-and-v3/)?

Comment: Steve, that's a near perfect example of what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: MrUpsidown, I'm planning on having a slider bar (like the linked example from Steve) that controls the time, and the arrow will reflect the new values for whatever time is spun in. Not much code is done yet, I'm afraid.